# How to authenticate a private Go Module using go 1.11 and Google App Engine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I've been updating my entire go gae standard project to use go 1.11's modules.

**Main directory structure**

```
app.yaml
app.go
go.mod
go.sum
```

**app.go**

```
package main

import "bitbucket.org/myPrivateRepo"

func main() {
    myImportantModule.Run()
}
```

**go.mod**

```
module myProject

require bitbucket.org/myPrivateRepo v0.0.1
```

**The Error**

If I try to gcloud app deploy:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build <GUI> 
status: FAILURE.
Build error details: go: bitbucket.org/myPrivateRepo@v0.0.1: 
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myPrivateRepo?fields=scm: 
403 Forbidden
```

(Note: obviously the repo I'm using has a real name).

So can I do it this way?  I'll admit to not fully understanding the migration documentation, particularly when it talked about "Moving files to your GOPATH".  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences

I mean, I thought one of the benefits of the new module system is that you don't need everything under the go path.  When I read https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules for example, it very early on says "Create a directory outside of your GOPATH:"

So, to be clear, right now all of my code is outside the go path, but everything builds locally just fine.

I think it all works becausego automatically downloads and caches things within the go path when I run go mod tidy / go build etc.

Yet it fails when I try to gcloud app deploy.  How would the google cloud build system ever have access to my private repositories anyway?  I'm obviously missing something important.  I also read you are not supposed to combine vendoring with the new module system so that can't be it.

I will be very happy if this works, as using DEP forced me to use goapp deploy very awkwardly.

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed some more useful documentation:  
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/specifying-dependencies. 

 It says:  "If you use Go Modules through a go.mod file, App Engine uploads only your application files and automatically fetches those dependencies."

I guess that's why it's failing, because it's trying to access a private repo without credentials?  

Right now I'm trying using the go mod vendor option.

Comment: Yeah, looks like private repos are not supported currently. Please help me bug google so they don't  deprecate the old runtime before fixing stuff like this =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE:  Google has some better documentation now that go 1.14 is out:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/specifying-dependencies

My solution:

Instead of dealing with credentials, I'm using go's module replace functionality to point GAE to use my local code.  This is working well.

**Directory structure:**

```
myService/
    src/
        service.go  // has a run() function to set up routers etc.
        go.mod      // depends on my private module in bitbucket and other things
        …           // other source files
    build/
        gae/
            src/        // simlink to ../../src
            modules/    // git ignored, I clone or copy my modules in build scripts.
            app.go  // see below…
            go.mod  // has main() which calls service.run() and appEngine.Main()
            app.yaml
```

**Method**

I use git module replace so that GAE uses my local code.  Before building I parse myService/src/go.mod to find the correct version of my private module, then I clone it into the modules folder.  I also made an option to copy wip module source code for debugging locally without committing to my module repositories.

go.mod from gae directory:

```
module myServiceGAE

require (
    bitbucket.org/me/myService v0.0.0
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.4.0
)

replace bitbucket.org/me/myService => ./src

replace bitbucket.org/me/myModule => ./modules/utils
```

**Pros**

The package under myService has no references or knowledge of GAE, so I can easily build it into a docker etc.  I think parsing the service go.mod files would be like creating my own dependency manager, defeating the benefits of go modules.

**Cons**

If I had a private module which depended on another private module, I think things would get too complicated.

Comment: This is a good workaround if you have a private repo, and you just want to pull in a bunch of private modules into a `/modules/` folder for deployment.  That said, it seems insane to me that google would not provide basic support to allow cloud builds to actually pull modules using the normal module mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to also use Google Cloud Secret Manager

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos

Google Cloud will have an SSH key to access and pull your private repository.

Answer (score -5):

Set git credentials before deploying:

```
git config credential.helper '!f() { sleep 1; echo "username=${GIT_USER}\npassword=${GIT_PASSWORD}"; }; f'

export GIT_USER=put_git_user_here
export GIT_PASSWORD=put_git_password_here

gcloud app deploy
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  I'm a little confused at how this works.  Does gcloud app deploy somehow transfer my git settings to google's cloud build system?  What if I'm not using git? What about all the other 3rd party repos that my project accesses, is this user name and password going to be tried against those as well?  Or if I have multiple repos with different required credentials.  I'm trying to figure out if this is safe / sustainable for a large system.

Comment: 'gcloud app deploy' may use 'go get' to fetch Go packages, and 'go get' depends on git to actually download the code. For accessing private repositories, git requires credentials that you can set by using 'git config credential.helper'. No credendials should be handed over to Google in this case. I don't know if you can avoid using git when you work with Go. I think you really can't, but I may be wrong.

Comment: No, you don't need git. Why would you? Also the clone happens serverside so I  don't see how this could work

Comment: This answer doesn't relate to the question at all. It appears the person responding to the OP is misunderstanding what the user is asking.  This response provides general information on how to provide credentials to git. It does not even begin to engage in how to do this within google app engine.