# deploying relative path go modules in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gcloud, google-cloud-build

my project's folder structure looks like this

```
/folder1
  /feature1
     feature1.go //package feature1
     go.mod
  /feature2
     feature2.go //package feature2
     go.mod
/web
  app.yaml
  cloudbuild.yaml
  main.go //package main (starts app)
  go.mod
```

this is inside my `/web/go.mod`

```
module mypackage

require(
  //3rd party packages
  feature1 v0.0.0
  feature2 v0.0.0
)

replace(
  feature1 => ../folder1/feature1
  feature2 => ../folder1/feature2
)
```

if i run `GO111MODULE=on go build` this compiles fine and i can run my project.

however, if i do a `gcloud app deploy`

i get the following errors:

```
go: parsing ../folder1/feature1/go.mod: open /tmp/staging614917184/folder1/feature1/go.mod: no such file or directory

go: parsing ../folder1/feature2/go.mod: open /tmp/staging614917184/folder1/feature2/go.mod: no such file or directory
```

these files definitely do exist in my project (otherwise the local go build would not have worked).

here is the relevant snippet of my app.yaml

```
runtime: go111
env: standard
```

before i switched to using go.mod, the app deployed fine via the gcloud cli.

however, i need to be able to specify a specific version for some of the packages i'm using, so i want to switch to using go modules.

with the above change, the gcloud builder works ok for the initial build step, but then fails on the app deploy step (gcloud app deploy)

does app engine not support relative paths in a go.mod? if so, is it possible to make this folder structure work?

EDIT:

this ended up being the key [How to authenticate a private Go Module using go 1.11 and Google App Engine Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663603/how-to-authenticate-a-private-go-module-using-go-1-11-and-google-app-engine-stan)

since in app engine deploys the root folder structure was not uploaded, a fix is to copy over the parent folders inside your subfolder where you house your app.yaml. then you point to that new subfolder in your go.mod using the replace syntax.

Comment: I assume you're `gcloud app deploy`'ing from the `./web` directory which then doesn't include copying the `./folder` directory along with it. I suspect it works locally but doesn't remotely because the `./folder` directory is not there. I'm learning `go mod` but I think you likely want to reference `./folder` using it's full path, e.g. `github.com/jon/folder` rather than the relative reference, treat these as distinct (separately managed|versioned) packages and have these pulled when not found.

Comment: ah makes sense. hmn, the repository is private, so it seems like gcloud would have issues downloading it in that case? i'm unfamiliar with how the builder works, but is there a way to force include folders?

Comment: I think the way to solve this is to make `./folder1` a subdirectory of `./web`. Revise your `import`s in `web/main.go` to be `web/folder1/feature1`. Remove the `go.mod` files except from `./web` and call the module `web`. I just tried this structure for you and am able to build and run locally and deploy to App Engine standard.

Comment: @Jon Please put the `EDIT` as an answer mark it as correct, it takes some to find the answer if its there in the question.